# preg_replace is not removing content between custom tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

The content on which I want to perform regex is this:

```
[NON-CA]
This is for Non CA
<b> In a New Line </b> 
[/NON-CA]
[CA]
This is for CA
[/CA]
```

I want to remove the content on the basis of country code of Canada, so if the user is from Canada the only `CA` part will be visible to him, and for others only the `NON-CA` part will be visible. The content between tags can be anything line breaks, spaces, special characters, HTML markups,HTML Entities. Here is the code what I wrote:

```
<?php
    $content = "[NON-CA]This is for Non CA<b> In a New Line </b> [/NON-CA]    [CA]This is for CA[/CA]";
    $CApattern = "~\[CA\](.*?)\[/CA\]~";
    $NonCApattern = "~\[NON-CA\](.*?)\[/NON-CA\]~";                       
    $NonCApatternsReplacement = array();
    $Replacepatterns = array();        
    $Replacepatterns[] = "~\[CA\]~";
    $Replacepatterns[] = "~\[/CA\]~";
    $NonCApatternsReplacement[] = "~\[NON-CA\]~";
    $NonCApatternsReplacement[] = "~\[/NON-CA\]~"; 

    if($country_code ==  "CA"){ //if its the user of country Canada remove the NON-CA Tag                                
        $result_p1 = preg_replace($NonCApattern, "", $content, -1, $count);                                                                                                                                
        $result_p2 = preg_replace($Replacepatterns, "", $result_p1, -1);
     }
     else{ //if user is not from CANADA remove CA tag and Text                                     

        $result_p1 = preg_replace($NonCApatternsReplacement, "", $content, -1);                                                             
        $result_p2 = preg_replace($CApattern,"", $result_p1, -1, $count);                                                                                                                     
     } 
     echo $result_p2
?>
```

So if a Canadian user comes it makes the content like:

```
[NON-CA]
This is for Non CA
<b> In a New Line </b> 
[/NON-CA]
This is for CA
```

which actually should be like this:

```
This is for CA
```

and if non-Canadian user arrives it makes the resulting text like this:

```
This is for Non CA
<b> In a New Line </b>     
[CA]
This is for CA
[/CA]
```

which actually should be like this:

```
This is for Non CA
<b> In a New Line </b>
```

It's not replacing/removing the part of the content that should not be visible to the respective user according to the conditions. Is there something wrong with my regex?

Comment: use `preg_replace_all` instead.

Comment: @Cylian there is nothing like preg_replace_all in php the 3rd parameters value of preg_replace if set to -1 it will replace unlimited occurrence of the preg

Comment: @PHPSeeker, I took the liberty of changing regex delimiter to `~` and unescaping the slashes inside the regex.  I find it much easier to read this way, and when your code is easy to read you tend to get more responses, more quickly.  Feel free to change it back if you don't like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `s` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) with this you will also match newlines with the dot `.`.

```
 s (PCRE_DOTALL)
    If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters,
    including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded.
    This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier.
    A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character,
    independent of the setting of this modifier.
```

I though of providing a shorter code:

```
$string = '[NON-CA]
This is for Non CA
<b> In a New Line </b> 
[/NON-CA]
[CA]
This is for CA
[/CA]';

$remove = 'NON-CA';
$result = preg_replace('/\['.$remove.'\].*?\[\/'.$remove.'\]/s', '', $string);
echo $result;
```

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Q8Y9z9).

Comment: Yep its working Thanks mate for the answer i was missing the `s` flag :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do all of this in one replace:

```
$country_code = 'CA'; // for example

$content = <<<LOD
[NON-CA]This is for Non CA<b> In a New Line </b> [/NON-CA]
[CA]This is for CA[/CA]
LOD;

$kr = array('CA', 'NON-CA'); // switch keep/remove
if ($country_code == 'CA') $kr = array_reverse($kr); 

$pattern = '~\[(?:' . $kr[0] . '][^[]++\[/' . $kr[0] . ']|/?' . $kr[1] . '])~';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', $content);
```

Comment: This throws an error, you have to escape properly the square brackets, furthermore it will fail at matching multiple lines, use the `s` modifier.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: I don't have any error. I have tested it. Closing square brackets don't need to be escaped, opening square brackets in a class too, and the \s modifier isn't needed here because i dont use the dot.

Comment: I forgive you ... This time!